# GObject (GTK3) TreeView: how can I activate row programmatically?

Tags: application-development, pygi, gobject

I've got a working TreeView with a ListStore as its model and selection set to SINGLE. How do I emit a signal to activate a specific row? I'm using PyGI.

(Sorry if this is basic; it's not in the Python-GTK3 tutorial and much of the documentation around is based on pygtk, not PyGI.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `GtkTreePath` to the row, and a `GtkTreeViewColumn` for the column, but you can use [row_activated()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-row-activated) on the `TreeView` widget you wish to activate from. Calling this will result in the `row-activated` signal being called, as well.